# Secure a php page from accessing it

Tags: php

I have an index.php page and I'm using

```
<?php include("default.php"); ?>
```

to get contents from default.php. Now i want that if someone directly opens default.php it becomes unaccessable or redirect it back to index.php page. How can i do it ?

Comment: you can do it in .htaccess

Comment: Have you done any research into this?

Comment: The way wordpress does it is by using constants. In your index file use `define('IN_APP', true)` and in your sub files use `if (!defined('IN_APP')) die();`. The annoying thing doing this and not just removing the files from public view is that you have to do this in _every_ file you don't want accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NiettheDarkAbsol's answer is the best one, but sometimes putting files outside of the public_html directory isn't an option. In this case you can add a check at the top of each file to make sure that it's opened by a valid file, not accessed directly. I do this by setting a constant at the top of files that can be accessed using `define('IN_SITE', true, true);` and then add the following to all pages not allowed to be accessed directly:

```
if ( ! defined('IN_SITE') )
    die('No direct access allowed!');
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want something accessed by the user, don't put it in `public_html`. The hint is in the name, it's *public*.

Instead, save such files outside the document root. You might, for example, have:

```
- /public_html
|  - index.php
|
- /files
   - default.php
```

From here, `index.php` can call:

```
include("../files/default.php");
```

But no user will ever be able to directly access `default.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Add above code in file which file you will include in other file. this code in default.php

```
<?php
if(!defined('MyConst')) {
   die('Direct access not permitted');
}
?>
```

And below code in file in which above file your including this code in index.php file

```
<?php
define('MyConst', TRUE);
?>
```

And other way you can achieve with the help of .htaccess add your all file in folder name include and in .htaccess

```
Deny from all
```

i hope this will helps you